# C# DataTable to Dictionary with multiple values

Tags: c#, dictionary, datatable

I have a DataTable that returns me data as follows:

```
APP | VERSION
____|________  
app1| 1.0
app1| 2.0
app1| 3.0
app2| 1.0
app3|
```

As you see, "app1" has multiple versions, and some apps don't have any versions. I need to store this Datatable result in some sort of List for later usage in my code, so I came up with Dictionary, but can't get It to work. Here is what I tried:

```
    public static Dictionary<string, List<string>> AppVer()
        {
         string SQL = "SELECT column1, column2 FROM myTable a LEFT JOIN 
         myTable2 v ON v.ID_FK=a.ID_PK";
         Dictionary<string, List<string>> versions = new Dictionary<string, 
         List<string>>();

         DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            try
            {
                using (var conn = new OracleConnection(conn_string))
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(SQL, conn))
                    {
                        using (OracleDataAdapter dad = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd))
                        {
                            dad.Fill(dt);
                        }
                        versions = dt.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary<DataRow, string, List<string>>(row => row[0].ToString(), new List<string>(row=> row[1].ToString()));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
             return versions;
        }
```

However, I get error

> "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a
>   delegate type".

How could I store my DataTable to dictionary ?

EDIT:

```
 Dictionary<string, List<Version>> all_versions =  AppVer();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var item in all_versions)
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("{0} - {1}{2}", item.Key, item.Value, Environment.NewLine);
            }

            string result = sb.ToString().TrimEnd();
            MessageBox.Show(result);
```

Comment: Btw, you know that there's a `Version`-class which you could use? So i'd prefer a `Dictionary<string, List<Version>>`

Comment: You may want to look at `.ToLookup` which is very similar to ToDictionary but for when there are duplicate values for the same key. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Chris, thanks, do you have any examples, I can't find any proper one ?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, never done that I'm not quite sure why I'd want to run DB connection twice for same data. If that is what you meant by class "Version".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `GroupBy` by the key, then you can use `ToList` on the groups. You know that there's a `Version`-class which you could use? So i'd prefer a `Dictionary<string, List<Version>>`:

```
public static Dictionary<string, List<Version>> AppVer()
{
    Dictionary<string, List<Version>> versions = null;
    string SQL = "SELECT column1, column2 FROM myTable a LEFT JOIN myTable2 v ON v.ID_FK = a.ID_PK";
    var dt = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        using (var conn = new OracleConnection(conn_string))
        using (var da = new OracleDataAdapter(SQL, conn))
        {
            da.Fill(dt);
        }

        versions = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>(0))
            .ToDictionary(
                g => g.Key, 
                g => g.Select(r => Version.Parse(r.Field<string>(1))).ToList());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

    return versions;
}
```

One of the benefits of the `Version` class it that it sorts correctly, so `10.1` after `2.1`.

Comment: thanks for this. I got It to work without errors, but how can I loop through values now ? See my edited question, that doesn't work.

Comment: @Lucy82: the `Value` is now a `List<Version>`, so you could use `sb.AppendFormat("{0} - {1}{2}", item.Key, String.Join(",",item.Value), Environment.NewLine);`. This will concatenate each app-version with comma. If you want a different delimiter change the first parameter of `String.Join` accordingly.

Comment: thanks for answer. I accepted It because you were first one :)

Answer (score 2):

```
ILookup<string, string> myLookup = dt.AsEnumerable().ToLookup(row => row[0].ToString(), row => row[1].ToString());

IEnumerable<string> myValues = myLookup["app1"];

// Loop through lookup.
foreach(var group in myLookup)
{
    string key = group.Key;
    IEnumerable<string> myValues = group;

    Console.WriteLine("Group {0} has {1} elements", key, myValues);
}
```

Comment: thans for your answer. But how could I loop through values based on a key ?

Comment: @Lucy82: I've just made a minor edit to the answer to make it clearer that the second line is fetching the data (I hope you don't mind, kara). At that point you have an `IEnumerable<string>` which will contain all your different versions that you can loop through as you would any other `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @kara & Chris, thanks for answer. I like this one too, but Tim answered in first place, so I hope you don't mind ;)

Comment: @Chris thanks! Lucy82: I added a foreach-loop to the example.

Comment: @Lucy82: Its entirely your choice which answer you accept. :)